# LSTM cell input matrix dimensions

Tags: python, matrix, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Im trying to build an LSTM using just numpy to try and get a feel for whats going on, but I'm running into an issue with my understanding of how the LSTM matrixes work. I found this image from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ of an RNN

[image]

From my understanding of an RNN, x<sub>t</sub> is dot producted with a weight matrix we will call W<sub>x,h</sub> and h<sub>t-1</sub> is dot producted with a weight matrix W<sub>h,h</sub> and the result gets summed together:

[image: f1]

This makes sense as the shape of x<sub>t</sub> is (b,d) where b is the batch size and d is the dimensionality, and W<sub>x,h</sub> is of shape (d,h) thus the resulting matrix would be of shape (b,h).

Similarly h<sub>t-1</sub> is of shape (b,h) and W<sub>h,h</sub> is of shape (h,h) resulting in a matrix of size (b,h) also. So summing these together would result in a (b,h) shaped matrix as the result, which is perfect as that's the same shape of h<sub>t-1</sub>.

Here is where I run into problems, looking at this diagram, also from http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

[image]

Things start to not make much sense. If we look at the equation

[image: f2]

I know that stacking h<sub>t-1</sub> and x<sub>t</sub> and doing the dot product with W<sub>f</sub> is the exact same thing as splitting W<sub>f</sub> into two smaller matrices and doing the same thing as we done for the RNN above, the issue comes in with the dimensions. The shape of x<sub>t</sub> is (b,d) and the shape of h<sub>t-1</sub> is (b,h). For them to be stacked on top of one another h must be equal to d, which isn't always the case.

So assuming I'm wrong about the shape of x<sub>t</sub> and h<sub>t-1</sub>, I'm guessing we need to do the dot products prior to passing into the cell so the shapes of x<sub>t</sub> is the same as the shape of h<sub>t-1</sub> (both being (b,h)). But even then we run into issues, by stacking the two matrices we end up with a (2b,h) matrix and unfortunately we can't dot product this matrix by any weight matrix to result in a (b,h) matrix, so progressively the number of rows in this vector would grow as more inputs are added in, as the output h<sub>t+1</sub> would be of shape (2b,h).

My question is what is wrong with my understanding. Looking at: https://www.quora.com/In-LSTM-how-do-you-figure-out-what-size-the-weights-are-supposed-to-be it appears that my assumption of doing the dot product prior to passing in to the lstm cell is correct, but for some reason this person said that post stacking the (b,h) matrix would result in a (b,h) matrix which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I would suggest starting from the the assumption of a batch size of 1. Now your input and 'memory' are vectors. Stacked onto each other they have a length of d+h. Your weight matrix is (d+h,h) in that case. Batch size should not change the weight matrix if I remember correctly.

Comment: I think your mistake is: x and h are supposed to have the same orientation, e.g. (d,b) and (h,b).  This makes it much easier to 'stack' them meaningfully.

Comment: Okay so lets say we manage to stack (d,b) and (h,b) we would get a (d+h,b) matrix as a result, that's not the same as the (b,h) matrix outlined in https://www.quora.com/In-LSTM-how-do-you-figure-out-what-size-the-weights-are-supposed-to-be that is meant to be multiplied by some matrix W_f resulting in another (b,h) matrix. Note this must be the case, it can't be that this matrix grows as h_t+1 must also have the dimensions (b,h) so is this guy wrong?

Comment: Unless W_f is (h,d+h)... then we would end up with a (b,h) matrix... Ah, thanks. You sure this works? It seems a bit strange doing all these transforms.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I assume your data is a column vector (1,d) and you want your hidden state to be (1,h). Than your matrix for the stacked column vector (1,d+h) should be (h,d+h). No transformations needed.

Comment: Definitions of LSTM equations can be quite different in every articles / posts. I understand you. I think people just do all the transformations as they see fit.